# Sonarqube installation

Tags: git, sonarqube

During installation of sonar scanner I am getting error like:

> "E:\Heena\Software\sonar-scanner\bin..
>   INFO: Scanner configuration file:   E:\Heena\Software\sonar-scanner\bin..\conf\so nar-scanner.properties
>   INFO: Project root configuration file: NONE
>   INFO: SonarQube Scanner 2.8
>   INFO: Java 1.8.0_101 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
>   INFO: Windows 7 6.1 amd64
>   INFO: User cache: C:\Users\ADMIN.sonar\cache
>   INFO: Load global repositories
>   INFO: Load global repositories (done) | time=779ms INFO: User cache:   C:\Users\ADMIN.sonar\cache
>   INFO: Load plugins index
>   INFO: Load plugins index (done) | time=35ms
>   INFO: SonarQube server 5.6.3
>   INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "windows-1252" (analysis is  platform dependent)
>   INFO: Process project properties
>   INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------   INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
>   INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------   INFO: Total time: 11.028s
>   INFO: Final Memory: 39M/84M
>   INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------   ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
>   ERROR: You must define the following mandatory properties for 'Unknown': sonar.projectKey, sonar.projectName, sonar.projectVersion, sonar.sources
>   ERROR:
>   ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging .  E:\Heena\Software\sonar-scanner\bin>"

If anyone know about that error kindly help me.  Please note that I am using windows 7 os.

Comment: Is this a `git` question?

Comment: Nope, it was regarding running sonarscanner. it is done. but the confusion is, when I put all folder regarding sonarqube in c: it will work and when I tried from another directory its through above erroe

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the log message:

> ERROR: You must define the following mandatory properties for
>   'Unknown': sonar.projectKey, sonar.projectName, sonar.projectVersion,
>   sonar.sources

It seems analysis should be launched with something like this:

```
> sonar-runner -Dsonar.projectKey=myProjectKey -Dsonar.projectName="My Project" -Dsonar.projectVersion=1 -Dsonar.sources=.
```

More information here:
[Analysis Parameters - SonarQube Documentation - SonarQube](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters)

And here:
[Analyzing with SonarQube Scanner - Scanners - SonarQube](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner)

Answer (score 1):

> I see two problems in your case.

- A. You are running `sonar-scanner` from the `sonar-scanner` install
  folder. (E:\Heena\Software\sonar-scanner\bin).
- B. You have not       configured the mandatory project properties for
  `sonar-scanner` to       execute.

> Following are the typical steps you can follow here.

1. Add `sonar-scanner` install folder
   (`E:\Heena\Software\sonar-scanner\bin` in your case) to system `PATH`.
2. Go to the Project root folder and the properties file `sonar-project.properties`. The `sonar-project.properties` file should have mandatory properties defined.
3. The four mandatory properties are `sonar.projectKey`, `sonar.projectName`, `sonar.projectVersion` and `sonar.sources`
4. Run `sonar-scanner` from the project root folder.

> Refer the attached screen shot here
>   [image]